# При клике на Resume скорость секундомера увеличивается в два раза,как исправить?

Tags: javascript, таймер

При клике на `Resume` скорость секундомера увеличивается в два раза.

```js
var interval = setInterval(Timer, 1000);
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;

function Timer() {
  sec++;
  if (sec > 59) {
    min += 1;
    sec = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("showminutes").innerHTML = min + ' :';
  document.getElementById("showsecond").innerHTML = sec;
}

function ResetTime() {
  sec = -1;
  min = 0;
}

function StopTime() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function ResumeTime() {
  var interval = setInterval(Timer, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span id="showminutes">0</span>
<span id="showsecond">0</span>
<button onclick="ResetTime()">Reset</button>
<button onclick="StopTime()">Stop</button>
<button onclick="ResumeTime()">Resume</button>
```

Comment: Надо же очистить предыдущий интервал, перед созданием нового.

Comment: А заодно где-то сохранять текущее время срабатывания - ну просто чтобы знать, что делить пополам...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей реализации при нажатии `Resume`, создаётся новый интервал, который также с фиксированным временем запускает функцию `Timer`, поэтому необходимо его предварительно удалить.

Таккже когда вы пишите внутри функции `ResumeTime: var interval = setInterval(Timer, 1000);`, создаётся совершенно другая переменная, которая не относится к внешней переменной `interval`.

```js
var interval = setInterval(Timer, 1000);
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;

function Timer() {
  sec++;
  if (sec > 59) {
    min += 1;
    sec = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("showminutes").innerHTML = min + ' :';
  document.getElementById("showsecond").innerHTML = sec;
}

function ResetTime() {
  sec = -1;
  min = 0;
}

function StopTime() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function ResumeTime() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(Timer, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<span id="showminutes">0</span>
<span id="showsecond">0</span>
<button onclick="ResetTime()">Reset</button>
<button onclick="StopTime()">Stop</button>
<button onclick="ResumeTime()">Resume</button>
```